What open source software are available for 2D skeletal rigging and animation?
I know that Moho is an excellent 2D skeletal animation software. Similarly, Spine 2D also has skeletal binding.
Are there any other open source software are similar? Are there corresponding open-source resources and/or papers where I can learn about the technology behind the software?

Have you tried an online search for something like "open source software for 2d skeletal rigging and animation"?

This was probably a better fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
